# Redirect Url to outside link after anchor tag is clicked - possible?

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection, squarespace

Here is the usual script tag that allows you to redirect to Google after 5 seconds.

```
<script>
        setTimeout(function(){
             window.location.href='www.google.com'
         },5000)
</script>
```

Is there any way to alter the behavior of this script so that it waits for a link to be clicked? Preferably an anchor tag?

Using pseudo code here is what I would like to happen

```
<script> 
     When the user clicks on Anchor tag #About do the following... 
</script>
```

Redirect them to Google

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.href='form2.html'
    },5000); 
</script>
```

In case you're wondering, the reason why I need to do this is because I am using squarespace which forces you to use code injection. I'd link the page directly but the navigation for the template (pacific) doesn't allow you to do so unless it is behind the other anchor tags.. To make sense of what I mean here is an example.

Anchor Tags in Navigation - Displays first in navigation

Outside urls - display after all anchor tags.

This solution I proposed would allow me to place the "About" link right beside "Home" but still be able to link to an outside URL. Can this be done?

Thanks for all responses.

Comment: Cant you just do <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

Comment: Not with making a squarespace navigation link on a one-page site.